# Computer restarts when put under load

Tags: reboot

I've got a problem with my computer for around one year.  When, for example,
I want to install netbeans or watch a movie for some time, my computer restarts.

I've got GeForce 7300 gt (6.14.10.9381 driver), Win XP, Pentium IV 2.40 GHZ.
Do you know any solution ?

Comment: Is there any possibility you are asking more from your power supply than it can supply? What your PSU capacity? Make and model?

Comment: 300 Watts.
It really seems that it's PSU problem.
Do you think it's enough?
What power should I buy if not?

Comment: @oneat: look at the specs of each component, add up the power consumption, multiply by 1.5 (just to be sure) ...

Comment: the problem is that I don't know power consumptions of each.

Comment: 300W is pretty low for a modern PC, particularly if the PSU is having other problems.

Comment: @onehat: so, did you come to a conclusion?

Answer (score 10):

it could be something else, but i tend to believe it is hardware, and the last time i saw such a behavior was caused by a faulty powersupply.

so i would start replacing one part at a time and see if things change.

Comment: +1: Sounds like a power supply problem for me. Theoretically it could be heat, but I tend to lean away from that explanation unless the machine is overclocked (though I'd make sure the heatsink isn't caked in dust or anything obvious).

Comment: @satanic: you obviously don't have friends with pets or that smoke or both who have "mysterious" computer problems that are cured with a vacuum cleaner ;)

Comment: @msw: Worse, I have cats. I actually bought a huge after-market heat sink for mine (because I hate the fan noise) so when the system fans kick in, I know that I need to clean the heat sink. You're right though: my first thought would be heat if I hadn't added any new hardware, but when it's other people, I generally assume that they have added hardware and don't think that it's "relevant" when they report their mysterious new problem.

Answer (score 7):

You should check your hardware.

...and make a Backup **right now!**

The first thing to do (after the backup) would be monitoring the Systems temperatures. [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) may help you with this. Install it, set it up to log your temperatures to a file and then do whatever you need to do to kill the machine. Maybe it's just overheating and the CPU (or another component) resets itself?

If this does not work boot from any fairly modern linux live CD (like ubuntu) and selevt "check memory" at the boot prompt. It will run memtest+86 which checks your ram. Let it run for a while (over night?) and complete 2-3 *complete* cycles.

Everything else will be hard to check. I'd reinstall windows at this point and see if the problem goes away. Otherwise: Change each component step by step (if you have spares).

Comment: Make sure to check the video card for exploded capacitors.  7xxx series Nvidia cards are notorious for that.

Comment: this all falls under "check your hardware!" .. and you will stumble upon the faulty part naturally if you exchange them one by one.

Comment: An alternative to reinstalling Windows is to boot some LiveCD (again: Ubuntu?) and try to crash you machine there by playing some HD Video or doing whatever kills your machine.

Comment: If it was a RAM problem I'd expect to see bluescreens not just random resets...

Answer (score 4):

Check for the CPU (more likely) or graphics card overheating. Watching video can take quite a bit of processing power, so this could be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

This may sound silly, but try cleaning your computer. Like literally taking a vacuum and compressed air can and cleaning out the dust. It may cause overheating or clogging some fans which may draw extra power from the power supply and overheat your processor.

Otherwise, it might be your power supply.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running this system with a 300W power supply, it is time for an upgrade. I would recommend no less than a 450W. With that out of the way, also run some full hardware diagnostics. The Hirens Boot CD should cover all of that. If there are still problems after replacing the power supply and anything that fails hardware diagnostics, then update your drivers and codecs. If, after all of that, you still have issues, time for a clean install. Beyond that, you either missed something in the diagnostics or it's time to retire the system.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a system heating problem check your system's fan speed also tried the following

trun off your system unplug ram and start the system it will give beep then turn it off plug the ram again and then start the system

give update after trying this.